# Injecting angular $locationProvider into a directive

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am looking to use the $locationProvider api to change to html5mode in my project. How do I inject this into a directive? This is what I have now:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.directive('errorModal', ['$location', ,
function($location, $locationProvider) {
    //to expose locationProvider to the window
    window.provider = $locationProvider;
}
```

But this gives that locationProvider is undefined. What would be the proper syntax here?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to try it in that way:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(function($locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($location) {
   $location.path('/my/path');
});
```

Inject $locationProvider in *config* and $location in *controller/directive*.